# How to have a function repeat until its value is the same as another function?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am making a program to present to the other members of the CyberPatriots club I am in. I want someone to enter a password and have it iterate through all the possible ways until it gets it, my idea is that it counts in base 10, which is converted to base 95 using asci instead of numbers, the problem I have is having it count until the passwords match. The code so far is only the converting part.

```
function generate(state) {
  const printables = ' !"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~'
  var ones = state % printables.length
  var newstate = Math.floor(state / printables.length)
  if (newstate !== 0) {
    return generate(newstate) + printables[ones]
  } else {
    return printables[ones]
  }
}
console.log(generate(10000))
```

Thanks!

Comment: `enter a password and have it iterate through all the possible ways until it gets it` Can you clarify exactly what you're looking for? The meaning of that sentence is unclear

Comment: I want the program to basically guess the password the user sets by iterating through all the asci characters until it gets the password.

Comment: so ... 95 ascii characters ... assuming a password length of 8 ... that's 95^8 possible combinations ... 6 quadrillion possibilities ... how long have you got?

Comment: It only needs to work. The design behind this is more so the fact that it is possible not necessarily probable.

Comment: well, what's the minimum and maximum length of the password?

Comment: Expected to run any length of the password, although using this method it will get exponentially slower the longer the password is.

Comment: Your code actually limits the max length to 8 (with a few length 9 being possible) - because of limitations of integer maths ... i.e. MAX_SAFE_INTEGER - but what you would do is use a for loop `for(let i = 0; i < Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER; i++) if (generate(i) === target) break;`

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I've gotten it to generate passwords of 11 characters.

Comment: what was the input number you used for that - add 1 to it - is the result different?

Comment: 1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000 I chose this number at random at it was 13 characters returning !plnIzQl[>&1$ entering 1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,001 returns !plnIzQl[>&1$. There shouldn't be any limitations, it is merely converting a base 10 number system into a base 95 number system using ASCII characters. This would, therefore, let it generate any possible permutation at any length of these characters, although the time it takes for a certain permutation could be much longer than others.

Comment: i.e. `generate(100000000000000008192)` results in `!__Ej2~nHK%` so you'd think that `generate(100000000000000008193)` would be `!__Ej2~nHK&` - except it's `!__Ej2~nHlQ` os what happened to `!__Ej2~nHK` followed by one of `&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP` ?

Comment: I belelieve the values look similar because of a problem it seems to have reconizing the space as part of the list of ASCII characters.                                               Disreguard this comment I was refering to my prior comment

Comment: or put another way ... `100000000000000008193 ... 100000000000000024575` all result in the same value `!__Ej2~nHlQ` ... because of the limitations of floating point ... any value for generate greater than `9007199254740991` will result in duplicates and, most importantly, **gaps** - in my previous example there are 40 passwords `generate` can not generate, ever - an there are 16384 values that generate the same result!

Comment: Gaps? Could you elaborate? I apologize for my lack of knowledge and thank you for the time spent assisting me.

Comment: Gaps ... `100000000000000008192` - generates `!__Ej2~nHK%` ... the next number up, `100000000000000008193` generates `!__Ej2~nHlQ` ... what happened to `!__Ej2~nHK&`  thru to  `!__Ej2~nHKN` `!__Ej2~nHKO` `!__Ej2~nHKP` - you can't have a number `n` that generates `!__Ej2~nHKO` for example - therefore, your code is flawed for passwords over 8 characters long (of course, the code would take several years to get to a number that high)

Comment: I see what you mean the further I go on the less effective it appears to be...

Comment: I see no errors in the way that I have written the code. It seems to work fine converting base 10 into other numerical bases, for example replacing the Ascii in printables with the number in base 16, Do you have any ideas why it fails to work effectively at larger numbers in Ascii?